Printed test page on Epson M2300 doesn't reflect real printer margins (Ubuntu 22.04)
I'm printing from my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS laptop to an Epson M2300 laser printer over a USB connection. CUPS is installed on my system.
The A4 test page results in a overly large left margin, and the right hand side is cut off.
The Epson M2300 AcuLaser manual states; "*Printable area : 4-mm minimum margin on all sides. (The printable width should be 202 mm or less.)"
The "Media Limits ..." printed on the test page should translate to an upper left margin of 6mm width and 13mm height. However, I measured the margin on the paper and the upper margin is 13mm (correct) and the left margin is 11+mm (not correct).
What I did so far;

I removed the printer from Settings - Printers,
I added it again with "Add a Printer...",
clicked on 'gear' icon, select "Printing Options" and "Test page" : see attached image.
clicked on 'gear' icon, select "Printer Details", shows "Driver Epson AL-M2300" which is correct.
printed another Test page with the same result.
in "Printer Details", "Select Printer Driver", selected "Epson AL-M2300 Foomatic/eplaser(recommended)",
printed another Test page with the same result.
"Install PPD File" and select the official Epson PPD ("Epson-AL-M2300-eplaser.ppd" version 1.1)
printed another Test page with the same result.

Any help is very much appreciated!


Is this printer driven by this specific ubuntu 22.04 system or perhaps a networked printer, probably driven through CUPS?

Info to add to the question needs to be in the question not in comments. Please use edit and add the info.
